# How exactly is this question "Opinion based"?

Tags: discussion, support

I am speaking with respect to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437400/what-makes-microsoft-word-generated-html-documents-so-large-in-code) question.

Is it my opinion that MS Word generated HTML pages very large in size ? You may try this on your PC and I bet, the code will truly be large.

I posted a comment on this post and later edited it to ask people how is this opinion based but got no replies. Are so many users, who marked this as opinion based talking about MS word's opinion?

Comment: Voting on meta is different.  It tends to indicate dis/agreement with your post or points being made

Comment: I too don't see why this close reason is appropriate. The question is clearly stated, backed up with evidence, and as demonstrated by the accepted answer, is objectively answerable.

Comment: One of those close voters, whose username may end in a number, has some of the strangest close votes and reviews I've seen in a long time.  It's like they just randomly hit approve and reject reasons.

Comment: @sphanley Sounds like people read it as, "why those silly MS devs add so much code bloat to my file when it's not needed?" rather than, "What does all of this added code actually do?"

Comment: Though, I never want to sound rude intentionally!

Comment: The answer you got was basically: "it is as large as it needs to be".  Probably best to assume that not everybody thought that was lovely Q+A that made the world a little better.  Is this actually going to make you do anything different?  I'd imagine a *useful* answer would have suggest specific ways to reduce the amount of HTML.  Well, that's unlikely to happen, you can still unmark the answer...

Comment: How is this even on topic?  This isn't about programming--its about how Word implements conversion to HTML.  Jeez.

Comment: In all fairness, you can ask the same on *any* application's binary file format -- including Word's own .doc and .docx. Try it: type your `hello world` into Word, save, then look at the file size. And mind that if it's a .docx, it's zipped to begin with.

Comment: "Why" questions are often opiniated. We often cannot know the exact reason why something has been done. Therefore speculation will take place. The truth is: Nobody outside of Microsoft knows why their generated HTML files are so big. Probably because they don't care enough to make them smaller. Just ask yourself: is this question really that interesting? What if we knew why, what then? I guess that often there is a more interesting underlying question like (I want to have small html code with Word, how can I do it) that are unfortunately not asked. In short:Why questions can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I saw your question when you first posted it, didn't think much of it except it was a harmless question about file formats, left it alone and went on my way. There were no close votes at the time.

I'm shocked to see it brought up here because it got closed. I have no idea why anyone in their right mind would think it is opinion-based, with or without the objective answers that have been given. I've reopened it now.

Comment: It's not opinion based; but should it really be a question on Stack Overflow? I'm having a hard time seeing the programming problem that needs solving here.

Comment: @George Stocker: There are plenty of technical questions that ask why something behaves the way it does without necessarily presenting a problem that needs to be solved. In this case, the question is "Why does Word generate such massive files for a simple 'hello world' page?" and the answer is "it's due to the OOXML format". While that knowledge isn't terribly useful on its own, plenty of developers work with OOXML on a daily basis and this would certainly be relevant to them, and it also teaches non-OOXML developers about the format.

Comment: we disagree that this is a programming question.

Comment: @George - if this isn't a programming question, then surely this isn't one, either? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why

Comment: @AdamRackis at least, that's about a tool commonly used by programmers. Word on the other hand...

Comment: @Braiam - surely SO still allows questions about less frequently used things?  I'd say Word is probably used more often than VB6, and that tag still exists :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Is word a programmer's tool used to program?

Comment: @BoltClock There's even a specific close reason used to close these questions; I've spelled it out in my answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Word is not a tool commonly used by programmers, unless the question is related to VBA. Programmer's tools refers to things like IDEs, version control systems, compilers, code editors, and so forth. What MS decides to include in Word's XML content is not even vaguely progrmaming-related (and the answer could be found by simply reading the generated XML to see what was there, IMO). I agree it's not "opinion-based", but it might be closable as off-topic because it's a general software question and not a programming question.

Comment: @George Stocker: Word may not be a tool used to program, but it, like other Office apps, is a platform for add-in development. If the file format is relevant to anyone at all, it's to an add-in developer. See also the [tag:ooxml] tag.

Comment: @BoltClock the question is _not_ about ooxml or about developing anything. I do agree that questions about Word and even questions about HTML generated by Word _can_ be on topic, but OPs question is simply garbage and I'm appaled to see it reopened. It fails to identify any specific problem and simply asks "why is this so long", when one quick look at  the source shows that it contains a ton of CSS and conditional comments that make up all of the extra lines. If OP asked "what do these specific lines mean `(insert conditional comment)`?" that would be ok, but currently it's far too broad IMO.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your point.

Comment: At least we all agree that the question was anything but opinion-based. I'd rather have a question reopened than leave it with an inappropriate close reason. At the very least, reopening the question makes it available for closing again - with a more fitting reason. I originally left the question intending to forget it completely, so from here on out I don't care if it ends up getting closed again as long as it isn't for being opinion-based.

Comment: A better question would have been why OOXML in this case is so bloated then. But it isn't really, one could reduce and optimize the HTML output of Word if only one wanted to. Technically it's possible. In the end it's more about the programming business, not about programming.

Answer (score 12):

The question is not opinion based; it is however, squarely off topic (according to the following close reason):

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used **primarily** for programming (*emphasis added*).

Yes, it's an interesting question; but it's still off topic.  Not 'Gee, it's tangentially related to programming' off-topic, just "This isn't even in the realm of things we are concerned with on this site" off-topic.

To address the concerns brought up in the comments:

> Word may not be a tool used to program, but it, like other Office apps, is a platform for add-in development. If the file format is relevant to anyone at all, it's to an add-in developer. See also the ooxml tag. - BoltClock♦ [14 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295478/how-exactly-is-this-question-opinion-based/295505#comment199696_295479)

But the question isn't about having issues with add-on development for Word, or the file size of an `OOXML` file causing issues. It's a general curiousity question whose answer doesn't have any programming relevance.  If the question were scoped to "I see this tag (insert tag here) in a generated OOXML file, and I need to know what it does" that's both a reasonably scoped question, and a question whose answers will actually help others.

> But this question is about the behaviour of [sic] word when used as a code generation tool, and about understanding its output in a way that could only possibly be relevant to a programmer [...].  –  Mark Amery [14 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295478/how-exactly-is-this-question-opinion-based/295505#comment199688_295505)

That's what's missing from this question: What behavior, and how that behavior relates to a programming problem.

The question, *as posed*, lacks any sort of reference or relevance to an actual programming problem. So what if the generated code is large?  Why does that matter?  What problem are you trying to solve where that matters? Are you trying to figure out what you can do to reduce it? Are you trying to parse out everything but what you believe a 'standard' HTML document needs?  Those are answerable questions (I wrote a parser in Perl a long time ago to do just that), and they're things we can help you with.

This question is flatly off topic; interesting or not.

Comment: Would this be a good fit for SuperUser?  That's part of that same off-topic reason right?  Just curious.

Comment: But this question is about the behaviour of word *when used as a code generation tool*, and about understanding its output in a way that could only possibly be relevant to a programmer. Word may not be a tool primarily for programmers, but this question is about its usage for development - and not just in a boat programming sense. The rule you've quoted is subjective; implement it too loosely, and boat programming becomes on-topic, but implement it too strictly, and questions about VBA or understanding strange browser behaviours become off-topic. This case is in the middle.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Why would programming the nav system or computer on a boat be off topic? Unusual sure, but off topic?

Comment: @MarkAmery the question is way too broad to begin with. It's not asking about anything specific. OP asks "why does Word need more than 400 lines for hello world and I only need 8" when one quick look at the HTML would show one that there are only 18 lines of actual HTML in there, and that the rest is CSS and conditional comments. And even OPs own HTML example is incorrect (there's no `<body>` tag); so the question is what part they don't understand - because "all of it" is simply not an appropriate SO question.

Comment: Yes I do missed the body tag but the question specifies the code is "W3C Validated" and that is enough reason for me to believe that '<body>' is not a compulsory tag.

Comment: @MarkAmery I updated my answer to address your point.

Comment: @BSMP Mark is referring to an old deleted question: ["Basically, the boat-programming question was at the core of what it meant for a question to be programming related."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/254929)