# Why can the poster of a closed question vote to reopen it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently I (along with 4 others) voted to close [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295501/62576). I was revisiting Meta, and noticed that the question had been reopened. I also noticed that it had been edited, and as I couldn't see any changes I went to the revision history.

I happened to glance at the list of users who had voted to reopen the question, and the first name listed was that of the original poster of the question that was closed.

Poster:

[image: Original poster of question avatar]

Reopen votes:

[image]

Clearly the person who originally posted the question wouldn't feel it should have been closed, and would vote to reopen it. This seems to be the equivalent of allowing a user to upvote their own question in order to recover rep lost due to a downvote, or to upvote their own self-answer and earn rep for doing so.

How is it possible that the poster of a closed question can vote to reopen their own closed question? And doesn't the ability to do so mean it's only requiring 4 votes to reopen it?

And if the person whose question was closed is by design allowed to vote to reopen it after an edit, why am I prevented from voting to close it again if the edit isn't an improvement?

Comment: Just like a post author can vote to close their own question after they realize they dun goofed, or they stumbled across a duplicate later.

Comment: @BoltClock: This doesn't make sense. Reversing voting on *someone else's question* or *closing your own question* makes perfect sense. Being allowed to vote to reopen your own doesn't. Clearly you'd vote to reopen it, because you posted it in the first place. If this is by design, the design appears to be very flawed - it's totally illogical to allow the same person whose question was closed to be one of those overriding that close vote. This is akin to allowing a person who posts a question to upvote it (or upvote a self-answer) and earn rep for doing so.

Comment: @BoltClock: Or perhaps more appropriately it's the same as allowing someone to upvote their own downvoted answer in order to regain the lost reputation incurred by the downvote.

Comment: True. Many people vote to reopen their questions without a valid reason simply because they don't want them closed, but some people do actually use their reopen vote correctly - to see if their edits were enough to fit the rules, or if [the close voters really were that boneheaded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295478/how-exactly-is-this-question-opinion-based). The other voters can determine whether the question is worth reopening. We'll have to see if the difference between 4 and 5 close voters is significant enough that a "reopen request" should be counted separately.

Comment: @BoltClock: *Other posters* should determine whether edits to a closed question were sufficient. Clearly, the individual who posted the question in the first place didn't feel it should be closed, and clearly they'll vote to reopen it if closure happens. Five users *did* determine that the question deserved to be closed, and five users *other than the original poster* should decide to reopen it. If there's no need to have 5 reopen votes, then why does the requirement exist? (I know this has been discussed before, but the logic then was "5 were determined as the appropriate number". (continued)

Comment: Now it's "5 was determined to be the appropriate number, unless the OP happens to disagree with the closure, in which case 4 is the appropriate number".

Comment: -1 because I think users *should* be able to cast reopen votes on their own questions but +1 because I agree with @KenWhite and think that while they should be able to, it should't *actually* count for anything. So... +0

Comment: @humble.rumble a user should be able to vote to reopen their own post but it shouldn't actually do anything? What would be the point?

Comment: To initiate a reopen vote?

Comment: A single reopen vote puts a question into the Reopen Vote Queue, with, if appropriate, a remark "This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?"

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, I understand that - what I don't understand is why the original poster is allowed to cast that vote when they are the same individual who posted the question in the first place. As I said, it's the equivalent of allowing someone to upvote their own question in order to compensate for rep lost to downvoting. And if the same poster whose question was closed is allowed to help reopen it, why can't I vote again after an edit to close it if it's not improved or changed?