# Would you please consider reopening this question?

Tags: discussion

I believe the following question

[Extracting text from garbled PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184304/if-pdf-copypaste-gives-garbage-text-what-is-wrong-with-the-pdf-source-code)

Should not be considered off-topic for the following reasons:

- PDF files are not simple text documents, it is a complex format that may contain programmatic instructions inside, in different programming languages (like Javascript, Postscript or the PDF graphics model which is similar to Postscript but not identical).
- The question has been heavily edited by an expert in the topic of PDF files, the close votes where cast against an older version.
- This is a canonical question in the subject of processing PDF documents, it comes up **very** frequently in SO in different ways. The most up-voted answer for this particular closed question is excellent, it covers the topic in detail and it can be used as reference for any future duplicates.

Examples:

[PDF text conversion results in gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727245/pdf-text-conversion-results-in-gibberish?lq=1)

[pdf strange characters on copying or with xpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958775/pdf-strange-characters-on-copying-or-with-xpdf?lq=1)

Additionally, in [stackoverflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) we find:

What topics can I ask about here?
- a specific programming problem, or 
- a software algorithm, or 
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
**- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**

I believe that text extraction from PDF files falls into the last topic. Questions about file-formats such as xaml or svg are not uncommon and are usually welcome, PDF has a similar nature and should not be treated differently.

Please note that I did not write the question or any of the answers, I am just a simple concerned citizen. I believe that closed questions are bound to be deleted after some time (please let me know if I am wrong), I think this question and its answer do not deserve such fate.

Comment: *"that is unique to software development"* - also most of the "answers" are garbage.

Comment: That also happens sometimes with regular "pure programmig" questions, I don't think that makes the question off-topic. On top of that, those answers were posted for the original version of the question, which I agree needed to be improved.

Comment: How does this question have anything at all to do with programming?

Comment: @GEOCHET Would you consider a question about how to interpret the bits inside an mp3 or jpeg file to be offtopic and not programming related? Or a question about how to get certain feature to work in HTML/CSS? This questions goes in that direction. I do see it is borderline...

Comment: By the way, the "ToUnicode" table that the up-voted answer refers to, is actually a postscript script... it would help if the answer contains a sample code of such a script?

Comment: I'm one of the close voters but I don't see enough value to re-open. The current answers appear to have some value, I don't see how re-opening will help in getting different or new answers that will be much better. FYI: closed questions with upvoted and/or accepted answers will not be deleted automatically. It would need a bunch of 10K-ers to delete vote it.

Comment: You forgot the "and" that occurs before the last bullet point. In order to be on topic a question has to fit at least one of the first three criteria **and** the last one.

Comment: @BSMP Interesting... I wonder why the are separated into two item then...

Comment: I normally see these types of lists written like this one with the conjunction placed at the end of the list item, not the beginning of the next one. But the requirements are written as: (1 OR 2 OR 3) AND 4.

Comment: @rene "closed questions with upvoted and/or accepted answers will not be deleted automatically". That was a very useful piece of information, I would not have brought this here if I knew that...

Comment: @yms I disagree with your "bottom line". A question that would present relevant parts of the PDF file (ideally an mcve) would get my support. What we have here is a question that says "I can't do this with some PDF of mine, why?" without narrowing down the realm of possibilities. Such questions tend to attract really generic answers. And in fact, this question *did* attract such answers. "When I use tool X, it works!" Who the hell knows whether it would work with the PDF the OP had? Nobody can tell.

Comment: @Louis Fair enough... actually my first comment on this kind of questions is always "give the pdf file". My intention was actually to save the answer, but it seems it was never in danger in the first place.

Comment: for completeness #yms [here are the Roomba rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/158100)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think extracting text from PDFs is something many people would want to do at some point in time for any number of reasons, and is not a problem unique to software development. XAML is something that only developers (and Blend designers) would use, yes, but I think SVG is also a bit of a stretch depending on whom you ask. While questions about authoring SVG markup directly are not unlike those about authoring HTML/CSS, there are many graphics editors out there that support SVG, and questions about their usage would fall squarely off-topic for SO. PDF, on the other hand... is something that is used by all sorts of people for all kinds of things.

While the problem statement doesn't preclude a programming solution, the question as currently framed doesn't really have much of a programming context beyond asking about the intricacies of the PDF format. [The last time I railed about a file format question getting closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295478/how-exactly-is-this-question-opinion-based/295479#295479), a whole lot of discussion followed but no consensus was reached as to whether such questions were appropriate for SO. I think at this point, if the question doesn't appear to describe a programming problem, then it runs every risk of getting closed.

I'm not sure if simply tacking on the word "programmatically" to the question body would help at all though in this case. All the OP appears to want to do is grab text from a PDF. They may be wondering out loud about the details of the format itself, but it's not the focus of their question.

tl;dr: I'm on the fence; while I see merit in the question, I don't think it's a particularly good candidate for reopening in its current state.

Comment: Is there any other SE site for which it is on-topic? (I'm thinkin if you can migrate it)

Comment: The question is from 2012; I can't migrate it even if I wanted to :(

Comment: Ah, Thanks. Better to leave it closed.

Comment: "I'm not sure if simply tacking on the word "programmatically"(...)"   It does not change much in this case. The question can be summarized to: how can I fix the content of a broken PDF file (programmatically or not, manipulating the bits directly if you want). The answer is that in general, you cannot without applying an OCR tool to every piece of text in the file. The problem is that you need to be a developer, specialized in the PDF internals, to give a proper justified answer.

Comment: @yms: No, you would need to contact the team.

Answer (score 6):

At least one problem with that question is that it is so general and has no information about the specific problem it is almost unanswerable.  Why is my pdf borked (read: "doesn't work")?  Dunno, could be a lot of things.  "I believe that this is due to embedded fonts and there are embedded fonts in the document."  Cool, why do you think that?  Without any proof, it could just have easily been poltergeists that messed with the bits.

Without any specifics, everyone is just left to guess what could be wrong.  I mean, look at the other answers.  They mostly consist of "try this, worked for me".  Even the most upvoted answer is still a "if it is this, you can try this".  And what if it isn't?  It certainly isn't bad information, but without the context of a specific problem it could be completely useless.

On top of that, it says "I have used all tools I could get my hands on and the result is the same."  While I realize this isn't a tool recommendation question, the way it is worded can attract the spammy "try this tool" answers.  And that isn't helping the case for this question.

Finally, it isn't a programming question.  Sure we use PDFs.  So does everyone else.  If your code is making garbled PDFs, share that and we can try to help with that.  That is a programming question.  If your question is how do I fix this PDF that I got from somewhere, then that isn't a programming question.

Overall, I don't think is worth reopening.  It would probably get closed again as too broad or with the same reason it is currently closed for.

Comment: "Without any proof, it could just have easily been poltergeists that messed with the bits." Actually, that is not true... the PDF format is very strict, it is unlikely that if you mess up with the bits you will be able to open the file at all, and even when it works, the probability of getting as only consequence that you cannot extract text is almost zero.

Comment: "If your question is how do I fix this PDF that I got from somewhere, then that isn't a programming question." Then according to you, a question about "how do I fix this html/xaml/svg/php/aspx file" will also be offtopic if the faulty part happens to be outside of a "pure code" part of the file...

Comment: @yms: actually there is a variety of possibilities for getting "garbled text when copied". Even when the file is *well* within the official specifications.

Comment: @Jongware yes, you are right, it depends on the type of fonts/encoding/etc being used

Comment: @yms "how do I fix this html/xaml/svg/php/aspx file", without a code element, would be off-topic, yes (mostly anyway, I'm sure there are edge cases). Maybe a good fit for SuperUser though

Comment: @Clive the file might have code, but you might not know if the faulty part is in the code or somewhere else. On any case, the bottom line seems to be that questions about the internals of file formats are off-topic. It is a shame, because it is something that only developers do in general.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true @yms, the problem here seems to be more that the focus is on fixing the file, not probing at the file format per se. That isn't really "unique to software development", as you've highlighted in the OP. Grey area though, I can kinda see what you mean